# Advantages of do { } while(0) versus ({ }) in a macro?

Tags: c, macros

There are plenty of questions on Stack Overflow regarding the use of `do { ... } while(0)` in macros, but this is a bit different. I understand why `do { ... } while(0)` is used to wrap multiple lines of code in a macro expansion. But there is another form I often see: `({ ... })`.

The `({ })` form has the advantage that it is an expression and can have a "return value". It also (subjectively) reads better than `do { } while(0)`. So why isn't it always used? What advantage is there to using `do { } while(0)` in a macro instead?

Comment: Note, in C++11 you can get a *similar* effect (as far as being an expression) with `[&](){/*...*/}()`, but it still has several disadvantages, such as being unable to `return` (need to implement rust-style `try!`) or use `decltype` on the expression (since lambdas aren't allowed in unevaluated contexts).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Because `({...})` is [a GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html).

Comment: Oh, OK... it makes sense now.