# Can someone tell me the name of the construct the following code uses?

Tags: c++, c

Let's consider the following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int err = 
    (
        { 
            int _err = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
                _err += i;
            }
            _err;
        }
    );
    printf("%d", err);
}
```

I have found it (or well, a more complex incarnation of it) in the gcc testsuite and I became baffled by the construct:

```
int outer_var = ( { int local_var = 0; /* do some work on local_var */ local_var; } );
```

If I remove the braces (or the `;` after the `)` ), it fails to compile, but with braces on it compiles as c or even c++. What it does is more or less clear to me (although I have to admit, this is the very first time that I see a single variable in a standalone statement (`_err;`) which actually has a meaning) but I just haven't seen this construct till now, so I'd like to ask if there is an official name for it in any of the C or C++ standards.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30576644/3233393), [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30490193/3233393)?

Comment: @Quentin Excellent catch, thank you! Now it is clear to me why MSVC does not compile it.

Comment: As an aside, that was (or is) a feature of Algol68.

Comment: Asideaside, happy anniversary 50 years Algol68.